# Android hot network question widget goes to current question

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-widgets

If the Stack Exchange app is already running and displaying a question in the background, tapping the hot network question widget does not switch to the tapped question.

Instead, the SE app will display whatever question was being displayed previously.

Comment: Originally wrote from mobile, after searching around it appears this has already been reported